REDCap, Calculated Text -- Apply Same Conditional Function to Several Fields at Once (e.g. print all labels for fields that the user picked "true" on)
I have a long survey in REDCap and we're wanting to generate a summary of all items the participant endorsed. They're all true/false.
So lets say the fields are named question1, question2,..., question20.
I want to make a new field in REDCap that pulls out the field labels from all questions marked true. This is of course done with a Text field that has CalcText.
But in terms of the logic I write into the equation for that, is there a code efficient way to say "print the Field Labels for all questions that the participant marked "True" on"? Or am I stuck writing out 20 separate if then statements?

A fairly simple option could be to have 20 descriptive text fields containing the questions' field labels and having branching logic so they are displayed when the corresponding question is answered true.
If you want them listed inline rather than one above the other, you could embed the 20 descriptive text fields within another. Something like this:
q1 true/false "Is Q1 true?"
q2 true/false "Is Q2 true?"
...
q20 true/false "Is Q20 true?"

q1lbl descriptive "Is Q1 true?" [q1]='1'
q2lbl descriptive "Is Q2 true?" [q2]='1'
...
q20lbl descriptive "Is Q20 true?" [q20]='1'

showtrue descriptive "{q1lbl} {q2lbl} ... {q20lbl}"

